# Yii2 запустить JavaScript-код из Контроллера

Tags: php, javascript, yii2, mvc

Создаю свою форму регистрации, основанную на Yii2-user. Но это не суть. А суть в том, что из контроллера `SiteController` мне нужно выполнить `js-код`

Такой способ не работает:

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>$.snackbar({content: \"This is my awesome snackbar!\"});</script>";
```

Для особо любопытных - actionIndex

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model_register = \Yii::createObject(RegistrationForm::className());
    $model_login = \Yii::createObject(LoginForm::className());

    if ($model_register->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model_register->register()) {
        // Вот здесь нужно выполнить функцию
        echo "<script language='javascript'>$.snackbar({content: \"This is my awesome snackbar!\"});</script>";
    }

    if ($model_login->load(\Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()) && $model_login->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }

    return $this->render('index',['model_register'=>$model_register, 'model_login'=>$model_login]);
}
```

Comment: Шёл 2017 год... `<script language='javascript'>`.

Comment: @Lexx918 Пахаха, самому стыдно, я просто попытался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так нельзя поступать, js надо выполнять в представлении, но не в контроллере. Просто в представление прокиньте какой-нибудь флаг, который будет результатом проверки `$model_register->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model_register->register()`, и в зависимости от результата выводите или нет нужный js.

Comment: Спасибо. Не подскажите, как это можно сделать? Проблема в том, что Yii2 не хочет рендерить еще раз `index.php` в `actionIndex()`. Поэтому я не могу даже обновить страницу.

Comment: Причем в логах пишет, что страница зарендерилась.. Вот код, который не может загрузить страницу: `return $this->render('index',['model_register'=>$model_register, 'model_login'=>$model_login]);` Он находится в `if` в `actionIndex()`

Comment: не понимаю в чём может быть проблема. Не могли бы прислать весь `actionIndex`

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался. У меня валидация была неверно настроена